# Static "Connection" in JDBC: Can connections get mixed up?

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc, web

Below is my code.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package DB;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

/**
 *
 * @author Yohan
 */
public abstract class DBMaster 
{
    public static Connection con;

 /**
 *
 * Initializes the connection
 */
    public void createConnection() 
    {   
        try
        {           
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            try
            {               
              con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB","root","");
            } 
            catch (SQLException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }            
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
        {
             ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void closeConnection() 
    {

    }

 /**
 *
 * check if the connection is successful or not
 */

    public void checkConnection() 
    {            
            ResultSet resultset=null;
            String cmd="select * from user";    

            try
            {
                Statement statement=con.createStatement();
                resultset=statement.executeQuery(cmd);

            }
            catch(SQLException ex)
            {
                if(ex.getLocalizedMessage().equals("No operations allowed after connection closed."))
                {
                    createConnection();
                    System.out.println("System Loaded");
                }
            }
            catch(NullPointerException ne)
            {
                createConnection();
                System.out.println("System Loaded");
            }

    }
}
```

As you can see, this is a super class, where the subclasses will extend. The sub classes will use the `static` variable `con` after extending. sub classes will contain the database code.

I have implemented this class in web applications, where JSP and Sevlet are being used. Now my question is, can JDBC connection "ever" be shared in web applications? The `Connection` is `static` here, so can "connection1" get mixed up with "connection2" and and do some nasty work?

For an example, in this web application, "connection1" is deleting a record while "connection2" is updating a record. "connection1" belongs to "web application user 1" and "connection2" belongs to "web application user 2". Instead of deleting the record, can connection 1 mix with connection 2 and perform the "update"?

As far as I know, this code allows very speed database access without issues upto now(tested only with one web application user), but I am willing to learn more.

Comment: Don't spin your own. Use an established connection pool library.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I know. I am about to use c3p0. But I have coded the rest of the application using the static `con` variable. Even though I use c3p0, I am expecting to assign "Connection" to `con` variable using the c3p0, so I don't have to change the rest of my code.